# Communicating with a background task in node

Tags: node.js, background-process

I have a task running in the background (downloading a large file from somewhere).

I need the client to be able to make an HTTP request and wait till the status of the task gets updated (for example, when the percent completion of the download changes).

Right now I'm using a hack - I'm using require() to get a singleton which keeps track of all the background downloads, and the background downloads store promises that get resolved when their status changes, so the request can just do downloads[id].promise.then(res.json.bind(res)).

Is there a way to do this without the global singleton, but also without using an external service like redis pubsub?

Answer (score 0):

@JonathanR, you're question is pretty vague on all accounts, but I might be able to get you started. If you provide more information I'm sure I could help you out. (What's the process? Simplified code snippet of what you do now?)

I'm not sure if you're familiar with [Child Processes](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html), but this should let you do exactly what you want. You can run any command you can call from your shell (if you use one), as well as spinning up other Node programs/processes. Lots of options, lots to learn, super useful.

Why I think it will work in your situation is that your main process could spawn a child process to manage the download. The child process can then send messages updating the main process when it needs to know something.

[Here's an example in the docs that might be relevant.](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_send_message_sendhandle) Cheers!

Comment: I have a working app already spinning up a child process. This is a design question.

The problem is that the process is running across several requests, and each request needs to access information about the process. Where can I store the process without putting it in the global scope?

Right now I am doing

"module.exports = []" in processes.js and "processes = require('processes');" in request.js

to keep track of their state. Is there a way I can avoid this global singleton?